# Two conflicting packages in one document — doable?

Tags: packages, incompatibility

I have two packages I want to use in the same document. Specifically `musixtex` and `tengwarscript`.

However they do conflict. Both packages use some of the same commands, obviously for very different things. Is there a way to load both packages in the same document, but only load one of them temporarily or intermittently?

Comment: The mind boggles!  Are you writing out the music to the Lord of the Rings??

Comment: More seriously, is it just the odd command or is it a lot that are in conflict?

Comment: You got it Andrew! It's nothing serious, just some fun with and for friends :) As I ran into the problem, well.. i wanted to see how to fix it should something like it arise in the future.

The feedback I get is:
! I can't find file `nur8'
! Emergency stop.

mfput.log is completely empty. This happens if I try to compile a document, empty or not, so long as both packages are called in the preamble.

Comment: I just did a bit of a basic look and could only find one command in common: `\Tten`.  `tengwarscript` looks pretty good at namespacing all its internal macros (with `teng@`).  Musixtex doesn't use that for anything specific other than to define it, so I would load `musixtex` first, then `tengwarscript` and use `\ttie` for the `musixtex` version of `\Tten` (since `\Tten` is just `\let` to `\ttie`).  Of course, I may be missing something else that conflicts ...

Comment: Could you add your code that doesn't work?  It sounds like the problem is elsewhere as when I try a minimum document then I get no such errors (though I find that my suggestion in the previous comment doesn't work; you have to load `tengwarscript` first, save the definition of `\Tten`, and then restore it after loading `\musixtex`: `\usepackage{tengwarscript}\let\origTten=\Tten\usepackage{musixtex}\let\Tten=\origTten`).

Comment: What happens if you only load `tengwarscript`?  If this is the first time that you've loaded it then you may need to install some fonts and fontmap files.  I don't remember the exact steps (was a while ago that I did it), but I do remember needing to do something.

Comment: tengwarscript is properly installed as of today. I just put in a few lines of notes and the inscription from the ring as a "proof of concept" if you will. How will I go about using the commands to save the definition of \Tten? I've used LaTeX for a few years now but this is the first time I've run into problems of this nature, so forgive me my 'newbie' status on this. :-/

Comment: I guess the error message I get must be due to my editor (TextMate). I get the error you mentioned when I compile the same code in latexit. That is to say: Empty document or not. Same error message, regarding \Tten.

Comment: It is not always possible. Most times it is about redefinitions. See also: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=alreadydef

Comment: I'll see about giving you a copy of the final document and code this summer :-) I'm trying to get it ready for an upcoming wedding. We'll see if it turns out to my satisfaction.

Comment: @Mr.V Hei, hva skjedde med dokumenten?  Gikk det bra?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Hi. Initially, yes. Sadly, I was sort of left alone on the project, and as I am by no means a musician I never got to finish the document. I was dependent upon a little musical assistance which never materialized. :/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Basically what was in my comment, but hopefully a bit clearer here.)

The only command that I can find which is defined in both `tengwarscript` and `musixtex` is `\Tten`.  In `tengwarscript` it is defined with `\newcommand` which checks to see if it has already been defined (and throws an error if so).  In `\musixtex` it is defined via a `\let` (which doesn't check), specifically `\let\Tten=\ttie`.  Moreover, there is no other explicit use of `\Tten` in `musixtex`.  So I would keep the `tengwarscript` definition of `\Tten`.  For the `musixtex` version, you can use `\ttie` itself, or define another command to be equivalent to it, say `\mTten`.  As `tengwarscript` explicitly checks to see if `\Tten` has been defined already but `musixtex` doesn't, the correct order to load them in is `tengwarscript` first and `musixtex` second.  The following is a way to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tengwarscript}
\let\tengwarTten=\Tten
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\mTten=\Tten
\let\Tten=\tengwarTten
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

(Oh, and I'd like to see the final document ...)

As Marc van Leeuwen points out in the comments, as `\Tten` from `musixtex` does not need to be saved (since it already exists as `\ttie`), the shortest resolution of the conflict is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\Tten=\undefined % \relax will do here as well
\usepackage{tengwarscript}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

(Providing no one has defined `\undefined`, that is.  If some idiot has done that then `\relax` will do instead.  However, I doubt that anyone could redefine `\undefined` or `\relax` without breaking some serious stuff so I think both are pretty safe, with `\relax` the safest.)

Comment: @Mr. V: I recommend using the method that Gonzalo writes (and therefore also accepting his answer) since it is a little more robust and works independently of the order of the packages.  You can always rename the saved symbol yet again using, say, `\let\mTtex=\origTten` if you so desire.

Comment: Since you figured out the conflict details, and `\Tten` from musixtex is not used is not going to be used under that name at all (it is not used internally, and the user will use `\Tten` for the tengwarscript version), I think a simpler solution is to first `\usepackage{musixtex}`, followed by `\let\Tten=\undefined` to remove the offending definition, and then `\usepackage{tengwarscript}`. This assuming that `\undefined` is what its name suggests.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Providing no idiot has gone and defined `\undefined` then it is ... undefined.  So `\let\Tten=\undefined` "undefines" `\Tten`.  You can do the same with any undefined control sequence: `\let\Tten=\someRandomRubbish` works fine for me.  So, yes, assuming that `\Tten` from musixtex is not used then your version is the shortest.

Comment: Yes, but I am amazed that the `\relax` solution works. But I've tested that after `\let\Tten=\relax` indeed one can use `\newcommand\Tten{...}` but one still _cannot_ use `\newcommand\relax{...}`. This means that `\newcommand` does not just test the previous meaning of the control sequence, but in case that meaning is the primitive meaning of `\relax`, it will allow redefining it _unless_ the control sequence is itself _spelled_ `\relax`. Very elaborate! Unfortunately I am incompetent at understanding the inner workings of LaTeX's macros, or even at locating their definition.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The test for `\newcommand` __explicitly__ tests to see if the proposed command name is either `\relax` or `\end` and refuses to define it if it matches.

Comment: And to fill in the last detail, the other part of the test looks to see if `\csname <command name>\endcsname` is equal to `\relax`.  This will be true if _either_ `\<command name>` is not yet defined _or_ if it is `\let` to `\relax`.

Answer (score 18):

As Andrew has mentioned, the general procedure to prevent symbol names clashes when two packages define the same symbol name is to load the first package, rename the conflicting symbols, and then load the second package. The `\savesymbol` command from the [savesym](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package can be used to this; `\savesymbol{XXX}` renames a symbol from `\XXX` to `\origXXX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\savesymbol{Tten}
\usepackage{tengwarscript}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the `savesym` package correctly handle stuff defined by `\newcommand`?  That is, when it saves a symbol, does it remove the fact that it is currently defined?  This would be worth knowing about (and highlighting in your answer) as my strategy only works because one package doesn't use `\newcommand`.

Comment: Nevermind, I just looked at the code and saw that it does.