# program, algorithmic packages conflict

Tags: packages, algorithms, incompatibility

I want to use both the program and algorithmic packages in a paper; however, after adding `\usepackage{program}`, algorithmic is now broken. For a reduced example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{program}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE a
\STATE b
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

This should print "a" then "b" on two lines; enabling the [commented] third line gives errors for me.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \AND already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \STATE
           a
? q
```

I'm using texlive 2010 via OpenSuSE RPMs.

Comment: What is the motivation for using the `program` package? I guess your minimal example does not effectively show its use.

Comment: @Werner, yes, of course, it's a reduced example. afaik algorithmic doesn't expose method names for recursive definitions. However, I'm finding more and more that it's a somewhat inopportune package, overriding sensible things like the absolute value / pipe character in math mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see at least two solutions:

1) Instead of using `algorithmic`, use the `algorithmicx` package, which gives you more functionality and flexibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\State a
\State b
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

2) Use the `savesym` package, and the technique I explained in [Two conflicting packages in one document — doable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18541/3954) to prevent name clashes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{program}
\savesymbol{AND}
\savesymbol{OR}
\savesymbol{NOT}
\savesymbol{TO}
\savesymbol{COMMENT}
\savesymbol{BODY}
\savesymbol{IF}
\savesymbol{ELSE}
\savesymbol{ELSIF}
\savesymbol{FOR}
\savesymbol{WHILE}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE a
\STATE b
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```