# The package marvosym seems to clash with the moderncv class. What can I do?

Tags: symbols, incompatibility, moderncv

I would like to use both the `marvosym` package and the `moderncv` package. LaTeX throws an error that `\fax` was already defined. While this isn't a problem on MikTeX, I'm currently editing a joint document on http://writelatex.com which will not proceed to compile the document.

Comment: *buy flowers and chocolate?*

Answer (score 14):

*Is this a problem with the native `\fax` command, or a problem with `\fax` existing in **both** of the the two libraries? The solution below assumes the latter, but can be modified for the former.*

[This pattern might help you](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-alreadydef):

```
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{moderncv}
\savesymbol{fax}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{MARV}{fax}
```

It should restore the regular `\fax` command while providing that command from `marvosym` as `MARVfax`.

[Here is another link about it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24854/program-algorithmic-packages-conflict). And [here is a link to CTAN for `savesym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/savesym).

Comment: This works perfectly.