# LaTeX Error: Command \widering already defined

Tags: packages, kpfonts

I keep getting this error whenever I start an article with the basic set of packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

I understand it's the command `\widering` being defined in two different packages at the same time, but I don't know how to get around the problem. How could I fix the issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It doesn't make sense to load both `kpfonts` and `fourier`: the second package will override the first anyway, as they both set the fonts for the document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two conflicting packages in one document — doable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18541/two-conflicting-packages-in-one-document-doable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Loading `kpfonts` together with `fourier` does not make sense: they are both font packages that define a font family (with accompanying math fonts) for the document. So, even if there were no error message, loading `kpfonts` before `fourier` would result in the former package being overridden by the latter.

So the remedy is simple:

- if you want the Fourier fonts (based on Utopia), remove `\usepackage{kpfonts}`;
- if you want the KPfonts, remove `\usepackage{fourier}`;
- if you want the standard Computer Modern fonts, remove both.

Comment: Package `yhmath` shows a similar conflict with `kpfonts`, while not with `lmodern`.