# Editing a script in cursive format

Tags: math-mode, fonts, italic, metafont

Good morning, everybody,
Well, I'm a beginner and it's really hard to find what I'm looking for.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to modify the script below that would allow me to write the header of this document in cursive format.

EXPLANATION: I've created a script that allows me to have the header in cursive format.

```
             \documentclass[12pt,francais]{article}
             \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
             \usepackage{lipsum}
             \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
             \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
             %\usepackage{frenchb}
             \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,epsfig,stmaryrd,bbm,mathrsfs,stmaryrd}
             \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
             \usepackage{fancyhdr}
             \usepackage{titlesec,graphicx,comment}
             \usepackage{frcursive}
             \usepackage{nopageno}
             \usepackage[top=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
             \usepackage{fancybox}
             \usepackage{shadow}
             \usepackage{enumerate}

             %%%%%%%%%%% FONTE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \usepackage[fulloldstyle]{kpfonts}
             \usepackage{mathrsfs}
             %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FIORITURES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
             \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}
             \usepackage{psvectorian}
             \usepackage{tikz}
             \usepackage[upright]{fourier}
             \usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
             \usepackage{verbatim}

             \usepackage{tasks}
             \usetikzlibrary {positioning}
             \renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{NavyBlack}%
             \tikzset{pgfornamentstyle/.style={draw=Black, fill = black}}


             \newcommand{\indic}{{\text{\usefont{U}{dsss}{m}{n}\char49}}}



             \DeclareFontFamily{U}{wncy}{}
             \DeclareFontShape{U}{wncy}{m}{n}{<->wncyr10}{}
             \DeclareSymbolFont{mcy}{U}{wncy}{m}{n}
             \DeclareMathSymbol{\Sh}{\mathord}{mcy}{"58}

             \makeatletter
             \newcounter{exo}[subsection]
             \newenvironment{exo}[1][]
             {\edef\@exer{#1}%
                \ifx\@exer\empty{}\else{\setcounter{exo}{#1:}\addtocounter{exo}{-1}}\fi%
                \refstepcounter{exo}%

                \rput[r](-1pt,1pt){\pgfornament[,height=1cm]{21}}
                {\Large $\mathscr{E}\mathbf{xercice}$ \shadowbox{\theexo }}%
                %\rput[l](2pt,2pt){\pgfornament[height=1cm]{23}}
                %\rput(0,0){\pgfornament[scale=.5]{85}}
                %  \noindent { \textcolor{black}{\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont \large {{\textbf{$\blacktriangleright  \mathscr{E}\mathbi{xercice}$ \shadowbox{\theexo }:}}} }}%
                \hspace{0.5em}}
             {\medskip}

             \newcounter{sol}[subsection]
             \newenvironment{sol}[1][]
             {\edef\@exer{#1}%
                \ifx\@exer\empty{}\else{\setcounter{sol}{#1}\addtocounter{sol}{-1}}\fi%
                \refstepcounter{sol}%
                \noindent {\it \underline{Solution de l'exercice \thesol}%
                    \hspace{0.5em}}}
             {\medskip}
             \makeatother

             \DeclareMathOperator{\var}{Var}
             \DeclareMathOperator*{\inff}{inf}

             %%%%% COMMANDES MAISON %%%%

             \newcommand{\ligne}{\begin{center}\vrule depth 0pt height 0.4pt
                    width 5cm\end{center}}
             \newcommand{\etoile}{\begin{center}$\ast\ast\ast$\end{center}}
             \def \cor {\noi{ \textcolor{red}{{\bf Corrigé :}}}}
             \def \fin {\hfill$\square$}%\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}






             %%%% PAS D'INDENT %%%%
             \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}



             %%%% Début du document %%%%

             \begin{document}


                \vspace {-3cm}


                \fontfamily{pzc} \selectfont

                \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
                \node[text width= \linewidth-2cm](Text){%
                    ~
                    \centerline{\LARGE \normalfont Université Djillali Liabes  }

                    \bigskip%\\
                    {\LARGE Département de Mathématiques}  \hfill {\large  Troisième année : LMD  } \\
                    {\LARGE Module: Analyse Hilbertienne}  \hfill {\large 2019-2020 }
                    ~ \bigskip \\
                    \centerline{\LARGE \normalfont  EMD  }
                } ;
                \node[shift={(-1cm,0.2cm)},anchor=north west](CNW)  at (Text.north west)
                {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{61}};
                \node[shift={(1cm,0.2cm)},anchor=north east](CNE)   at (Text.north east)
                {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=v]{61}};
                \node[shift={(-1cm,-0.5cm)},anchor=south west](CSW) at (Text.south west)
                {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
                \node[shift={(1cm,-0.5cm)},anchor=south east](CSE)  at (Text.south east)
                {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
                \node[shift={(0cm,0cm)}](CS) at (Text.south)
                {\pgfornament[width=4cm,ydelta=+2cm]{75}};
                \pgfornamenthline{CNW}{CNE}{north}{89}
                \pgfornamentvline{CNW}{CSW}{west}{87}
                \pgfornamentvline{CNE}{CSE}{east}{87}
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \fontfamily{ptm} \selectfont


                \begin{cursive}
                    \begin{exo}\\

                        \textit{Soit $H$ un espace de Hilbert et $F \subset H$ un sous-espace vectoriel fermé non vide. Montrer que l'opérateur de projection vérifie les propositions suivantes:} 
                        \begin{enumerate}
                            \item  \textit{$P_F$ est linéaire et idempotent i.e $P_F\circ P_F = P_F$.}
                            \item $F \oplus F^{\perp}= H.$
                            \item  \textit{$P_F$ est $1$-Lipschitzienne (donc continue), i.e $\forall x\in H, \quad  \lVert P_F(x)\rVert \leqslant \lVert x \rVert $.} 
                            \item $\mathrm{Ker}P_F = F^{\perp}.$
                        \end{enumerate} 
                    \end{exo}

                 \end{cursive}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node[shift={(-1cm,-0.5cm)},anchor=south west](CSW)  at  
       (Text.south west) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,height=1cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
                \node[shift={(1cm,-0.5cm)},anchor=south east] (CSE)  at  
       (Text.south east) {\pgfornament[width=1cm,symmetry=c]{61}};
                \node[shift={(0cm,0cm)}]                      (CS)   at  
       (Text.south)      {\pgfornament[width=4.5cm]{75}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
             \end{document}
```

I hope I was understandable.

I thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The internet link you give is invalid.

Comment: Your code is OK, but Loading `kpfonts` together with `fourier` does not make sense. Look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173749/31034.

Comment: Off-topic: `mathtools` loads `amsmath`, so it's not necessary to specify both.  And other packages are specified multiple times, including `stmaryrd`.  So could be cleaned up.